# How should I clean and lubricate gearing for casement windows?

Tags: windows, lubrication

My house has casement windows. I opened their gearing boxes to mask them because I painting the frames and I noticed them dirty.

How should I clean and lubricate them?

I was thinking vacuum with micro dust attachments and white silicone grease.

Comment: I think a silicon spray would be less likely to eventually get clogged up with dirt.

Answer (score 2):

> I was thinking vacuum with micro dust attachments and white silicone
>   grease.

That's what I would do. Not too much grease though.

Comment: Hi. This was automatically "flagged as low-quality because of its length and content." You might want to explain what "that" is.